# Programming practice: Does not creating variables at first lead to faster computation?

Tags: matlab

I have `a`, `b` and `A`.

```
a = some expression 1
b = some expression 2
A = a + b
```

vs

```
A = some expression 1 + some expression 2
```

In my code, there are not just `a` and `b` but a lot of those. By using the later method without creating variables at first, i.e. by just summing all the expressions in `A`, I get 1s faster in my program, total is about 11s. This is confirmed after a long of tests. So it reduces from 11s to about 10s. Is this due to just not creating variables at first? Does not creating variables at first lead to faster computation?
I need to run a lot of `for` loop and run ode solver and for long computation. Variables are calculated and created inside the loop. If i can get a about 10% decrease this is good.

Comment: I'm not an expert about what goes on under the hood in MATLAB, but I expect that variable assignment is not a very expensive operation. How complex are `some expression 1` and `2`? Can you edit your question to include them? Did you make sure to include a `clear;` command between each version to make sure that nothing is getting cached in between?

Comment: @eigenchris They are large matrices. The calculation is very complex but i think the calculation needs to be carried out in both cases.

Comment: @eigenchris no i did not use `clear` command.

Comment: @eigenchris Does variable assignment cost time? Will the time scale up if I do this a lot of time in loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general (not just MATLAB).

Your first scenario these additional steps are required, which do not apply to the second scenario.

1. When variable is created, memory needs to be allocated where the value for the variable can be stored.
2. When a value is assigned to that variable, that value needs to be written to the variable's space in memory.
3. When the calculation is requested, the value for each variable needs to be retrieved from memory.

Many compilers optimize away these additional overheads by using various techniques, but many interpreted languages do not. (This is not a hard and fast rule though, there are smart interpreted languages and stupid compiled ones).

I do not know exactly how the internals of MATLAB works, but I do think it is 
interpreted, which means that the additional steps likely will incur additional overhead.

The problem with your second scenario is that is less readable and maintainable in the long run though. It is easier to read computations and intermediate steps when variable names are used. The trick is balance performance and readability.

Comment: Thanks. Will the time scale up if I do this a lot of time in loop? or stay the same independent of how many loops i run? The size of variables do not change.

Comment: If you declare new variables in the loop, the overhead for the declaration will take effect. If you assign a value to a variable in the loop, the overhead for the assignment will take effect, and so forth. In other words, it depends on what the code in the loop is.

Comment: The size of variables do not change. So memory size should stay the same. So does the time cost only exist in the first loop?

Comment: It depends on what part of the code is in the loop. But if the matrix already is the correct size before the loop starts, the only cos you will have inside the loop is assigning the value to some index in the matrix.

Comment: The next question would be, how long does your total program run, that you would care about a 10% improvement? If you really want help with tuning your code for performance, I suggest you post the source code, or at least the basic elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much of a difference it would make in terms of performance, but I don't think it would be a sizeable difference. Maybe a few hundredths of a second. 
You can test it for yourself by using the tic toc function.

```
tic
a = some expression 1
b = some expression 2
A = a + b
toc
```

VS

```
tic
A = some expression 1 + some expression 2
toc
```

As mentioned in the other answer, readability is the main difference. You want to keep your code as simple as possible so that if there is a problem you know exactly where it is and hopefully why there was a problem!